Is it possible to use .NET Aspire with a .NET 6 app?
We have multiple .NET 6 apps and background workers which are hosted on Azure Container apps.
These are built on .NET 6.0 today.
Is it possible to use Aspire to orchestrate them?

no, it is not, ASPIRE is for .net 8, so why not bump your .net 6 to .net 8 and try

YES YOU CAN up to a point. You can even use it with Python, Java etc as long as you register the services. You'll have to make some configurations by hand though. The Dashboard can be used as a target for any application that emits OpenTelemetry data.

The orchestration project is special. The target framework of the orchestration project does not affect what it can orchestrate. This means you can launch a .NET 6/7/8 application. As others have said, to get the full set of aspire features it requires .NET 8+. The Aspire.* packages depend on .NET 8 features to  get the full end to end experience working including telemetry, resilience etc.
Upgrading from .NET 6 to 8 should be straightforward.

You should probably explain what the missing features are. If I register a FastAPI service (with the correct OTEL configuration), what do I miss, beyond the manual config work?

And even in .NET 8, ASP.NET Core OData won't work because of the way it uses HttpClient

What does "won't work" mean?

There's an open issue in OData.NET about this, possibly fixed only in the next version. The library injects HttpClientHandler instances instead of HttpClient or using HttpClientFactory, so it never sees Aspire's registrations. You can create an OData API but other projects don't see it. Trying to use Aspire with OData was the first thing I tried after the first toy projects because I've built a Blazor hosted reporting site 3 years ago, using OData as the API. Not the first time I though I should probably rewrite with GraphQL/HotChocolate ....

PS: the database component docs should probably show how to specify database passwords. It's easy for new users to get confused
